# mongodb nested unwind and remove duplicates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have a user collection

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"61375acc1c7d0a1a6e6005f0"},
"fullName":"VishnuMohan",
"email":"vishnu@gmail.com",
"password":password,
"avatar":"avatar",
"friends":[],
"friendRequests":[]
}
```

and a posts collection with documents in this format

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"613b725d68398c8f149db2e3"},
"postContent":"vishnu 1",
"medias":["medias.jped"],
"createdAt":{"$date":"2021-09-10T14:57:33.407Z"},
"userId":{"$oid":"61375acc1c7d0a1a6e6005f0"},
"authorName":"VishnuMohan",
"likes":[],
"comments":[]
}
```

I want to get each users data including post details and the medias inside it

I tried a simple aggregation using lookup and was able to get user's posts like this.

```
id:61375acc1c7d0a1a6e6005f0
fullName:"Vishnu Mohan"
email:"vishnu@gmail.com"
password:"$2b$10$Yrs5H3mYrM8xLwWlek3K7uAs.EOLsXggj6wV7oSflPlPjo1ZkFem6"
avatar:"https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/vishnu@gmail.com.svg"
friendRequests:Array
friends:Array
posts:[
{
_id:613b725d68398c8f149db2e3
postContent:"post 1"
medias:["media2.jpeg"]
createdAt:2021-09-10T14:57:33.407+00:00
userId:61375acc1c7d0a1a6e6005f0
authorName:"Vishnu Mohan"
avatar:"https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/vishnu@gmail.com.svg"
likes:Array
comments:Array
},
{
_id:613b725d68398c8fasdfgasdf
postContent:"post 2"
medias:["media3.jpeg","media4.jpeg"]
createdAt:2021-09-10T14:57:33.407+00:00
userId:61375acc1c7d0a1a6e6005f0
authorName:"Vishnu Mohan"
avatar:"https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/vishnu@gmail.com.svg"
likes:Array
comments:Array
}
]
```

now I want to unwind posts Array and unwind the medias and get a desired output as such:

```
id:61375acc1c7d0a1a6e6005f0
fullName:"Vishnu Mohan"
email:"vishnu@gmail.com"
password:"$2b$10$Yrs5H3mYrM8xLwWlek3K7uAs.EOLsXggj6wV7oSflPlPjo1ZkFem6"
avatar:"https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/vishnu@gmail.com.svg"
friendRequests:Array
friends:Array
posts:[
{
_id:613b725d68398c8f149db2e3
postContent:"post 1"
medias:["media2.jpeg"]
createdAt:2021-09-10T14:57:33.407+00:00
userId:61375acc1c7d0a1a6e6005f0
authorName:"Vishnu Mohan"
avatar:"https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/vishnu@gmail.com.svg"
likes:Array
comments:Array
},
{
_id:613b725d68398c8fasdfgasdf
postContent:"post 2"
medias:["media3.jpeg","media4.jpeg"]
createdAt:2021-09-10T14:57:33.407+00:00
userId:61375acc1c7d0a1a6e6005f0
authorName:"Vishnu Mohan"
avatar:"https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/vishnu@gmail.com.svg"
likes:Array
comments:Array
}
],
//new field named medias storing the values of medias array from all posts
medias:["media2.jpeg","media3.jpeg","media4.jpeg]
```

I'm looking for a way to get the values from the medias array within the posts array objects and pipe it in an array on the outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- reduce starting with `[]` and concat the medias arrays of all posts
- union with `[]` to remove duplicates (its faster to check for duplicates 1 time compared with each concat)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zyWv-X5aCAQ)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "medias": {
        "$setUnion": [
          {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$posts",
              "initialValue": [],
              "in": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  "$$this.medias"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```